# Execution command is not working correctly

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I have this command in the crontab

```
 bash /opt/database/pg_backup_rotated.sh -c /opt/database/pg_backup.config >> /opt/data/logs/daily-database_dump.log 2>&1
```

and in the.bashrc I have `PG_PASSWORD` supplied for the backup user.
The crontab stops by asking password while executing the above command through the terminal and works fine (it does not ask for a password). What is wrong?

I am using instructions from there to backup: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux

Comment: cron executes bash *non-interactively*, which bypasses your `PG_PASSWORD` assignment in ~/.bashrc

Comment: @steeldriver thx for the response. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pg_dump` in your backup script, it can read from `~/.pgpass` in the home directory of the calling user. So create a `~/.pgpass` file with the password in it.

`hostname:port:database:username:password`

For example:

`localhost:5432:application_production:application:OukaaKu9oleif4Oomee2Gubaw9shie7h`

[Here's the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) about that file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am not using pg_dump. I have added the link for my method

Comment: Those scripts appear to call `pg_dump`?

Comment: yeap. okay i will try